# Avoid closing WebBrowser control if browser is closed from website javascript C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to host WebBrowser control in my C# winforms application in order to open a website of Customer. Customer's website is frequently trying to close the WebBrowser by Javascript code. How can I stop my WebBrowser getting closed?

I am implementing ExtendedWebBrowser class as below:

```
// A delegate type for hooking up close notifications.
public delegate void ClosingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

// We need to extend the basic Web Browser because when a web page calls
// "window.close()" the containing window isn't closed.
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    // Define constants from winuser.h
    private const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x210;
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 2;

    public event ClosingEventHandler Closing;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
                if (!DesignMode)
                {
                    if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_DESTROY)
                    {
                        Closing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
                DefWndProc(ref m);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A website shouldn't try to close a browser imho. What does not work about your current code? Does it fire `case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
                if (!DesignMode)
                {
                    if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_DESTROY)
                    {
                        Closing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
                DefWndProc(ref m);
                break;`?

Comment: with this code i want to know, how i can present my WebBrowser from closing?

Comment: Maybe not call `Closing()`?

Comment: Closing() is the custom event I am calling to inform the Parent Form Control that the WebBrowser control is now closed. I want to know, how i can avoid closing my WebBrowser control.

Comment: Ah I think I know, not near a PC ATM so can't test but think you have to set the message value (to handled) and return I think 1 instead of break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms632638(v=vs.85)), when you handle the WM_PARENTNOTIFY message you have to take only the LOWORD value of wParam to check for WM_DESTROY message. You should filter value like this :

```
if ((wParam.ToInt32() & 0x0000FFFF) == WM_DESTROY)
```

Historically a "word" is 16-bits, so wParam is a "double-word" (dword) which contains two 16-bits values. The first value is stored in the two lower bytes and the second in the two higher.